# Set Sequence Generator allocationSize to 1 for all subclasses via parent class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I was going through this Oracle Docs on [`@SequenceGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee%2F6%2Fapi%2F%2F/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html).

And I was wondering on how to override the `@SequenceGenerator` with `allocationSize` to `1` for all entities (let's say Order & Purchase) at a **global** level. By default it is `50`.

**BaseIdentifier:**

```
public class BaseIdentifier {
     
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id; 
    
    // .... constructors, other member variables, getters and setters
}
```

**Order:**

```
@Entity
public class Order extends BaseIdentifier {
     // .... constructors, member variables, getters and setters
}
```

**Purchase:**

```
@Entity
public class Purchase extends BaseIdentifier {
     // .... constructors, member variables, getters and setters
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
 Hibernate: 
        create sequence orders_seq start with 1 increment by 50
```

I can't set the `@SequenceGenerator` at the entity level since it inherits the `@Id` definition from Base which is common for all entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `@GenericGenerator` instead of going for `@SequenceGenerator` to get more granular control to generate sequences.

Found a hacky way via `SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY_SUFFIX` to generate the sequences for subclasses without even modifying them.

Try this:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator;

@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseIdentifier {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "custom_gen")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "custom_gen", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY_SUFFIX, value = "_seq"),
                    @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INITIAL_PARAM, value = "1"),
                    @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1")})
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

}
```

Order_Table:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Order_Table extends BaseIdentifier {

}
```

Purchase:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;

@Entity
public class Purchase extends BaseIdentifier {

}
```

Spring Boot logs:

[image]

**I've tested with Oracle DB, it's working.**

ORDER_TABLE:

[image]

PURCHASE:

[image]

ORDER_TABLE_SEQ:

[image]

PURCHASE_SEQ:

[image]

Comment: Its a single sequence generator custom_gen which is shared by Order, Purchase so it wouldn't be sequential correct. It has to be unique and sequentially incremented by 1. If there is a way to pass the sequence name from derived class to base class that might help, not sure how

Comment: @user352290 I have updated my answer. Please have a look.